# Could planetary magnetic fields repel each other?

Tags: magnetic-fields, orbital-motion, planets, geomagnetism

If two planets with magnetospheres approached each other, would they repel or attract?

Comment: I think that interaction would be negligible compared to their gravitational attraction.

Answer (score 1):

The magnetic field of each planet would be irrelevant compared to the gravitational pull between them.

As to whether or not the magnetic force (tiny) would be repulsive or attractive, it's pretty much a 50-50 chance, determined by the relative orientation of each planet's magnetic dipole moment.